# add data to a list view from database

Tags: android

i want to add some info from my database to a list view, i have been able to pass that information to a textView just don't know how to get it to a list view this is my code.

```
   public class ViewClass extends Activity{
       ListView myList;
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
        Initialize();
        Database viewAgenda = new Database(this);
        viewAgenda.open();
        String data = viewAgenda.getAgendaData();
        viewAgenda.close();
        test.Add(data);
}
     private void Initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.panel_bottom);

    }


}
```

Comment: You need to learn how adapter work. Googling : "listview adapter tutorial" or something like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data you get from the `Database` in `ArrayList` and then add this arraylist in `List`

```
ArrayList<String> list_data = new ArrayList<>();
list_data.add("item"); // likewise add list items here

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, list_data);
myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: myList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,test));

Comment: yes you can directly assign the adapter without making the variable

Answer (score 0):

here is Example

http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Displaying_Data_with_ListView_and_BaseAdapter_(Android)
http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html

may be helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the adapter class to link a database with a ListView. Please see the below code.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(The Id of your ListView);
//fetch your data to a  Cursor
Cursor c = "The result of a select statement";        
SimpleCursorAdapter adap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.item2,//Your layout for the list view 
            c, 
            new String[]{"fullname", "balance"}, //field names
            new int[]{R.id.rowData, R.id.rowMoney});//The ids of elements from your list view layout. The field "fullname" will be loaded into the "R.id.rowData" element.     
lv.setAdapter(adap);
```